Bitlocker recovery key back-up to AAD and Intune
In the tenant there are devices without a Bitlocker recovery key. We want these devices to back up their recovery key to AAD and subsequently to Intune.
All devices are AADJ and there is no on-premise AD.
Backing up the key to AAD results in an error. We tried to back this up using the manage-bde cmdlet and script utlizing the BackupToAAD-BitLockerKeyProtector command. Example script:
Connect-AzureAD

$BitlockerVol = Get-BitLockerVolume -MountPoint $env:SystemDrive
$BPID = ""
foreach ($BP in $BitlockerVol.KeyProtector) {
    if ($BP.KeyProtectorType -eq "RecoveryPassword") {
        $BPID = $BP.KeyProtectorId
        break
    }
}

BackupToAAD-BitLockerKeyProtector -MountPoint "$($env:SystemDrive)" -KeyProtectorId $BPID

These two give a JSON error and don't work.
BackupToAAD-BitLockerKeyProtector: JSON value not found. (Exception from HRESULT: 
0x83750009)

    At C:\Untitled1.ps1:12 char:1
    + BackupToAAD-BitLockerKeyProtector -MountPoint "$($env:SystemDrive)" - ...
    + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], COMException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException,BackupToAAD 
       -BitLockerKeyProtector

 

We tried to rotate the recovery key via Intune. This also doesn't work and returns a JSON error viewable in the event viewer. Also in event viewer it says the device doesn't have access to the bitlocker information in AAD in order to retrieve it. Changing settings in the Bitlocker endpoint security policies also didn't fix the issue.
Is there anyway to fix this or what could be the cause of this problem?
Edit: running the command with the debug switch returns:
DEBUG: Begin BackupToAAD-BitLockerKeyProtector(C:, {*})
DEBUG: Begin Get-BitLockerVolumeInternal(C:)
DEBUG: Begin Get-Win32EncryptableVolumeInternal(C:)
DEBUG: Filtering Win32_EncryptableVolumes by C:
DEBUG: End Get-Win32EncryptableVolumeInternal. Return Win32_EncryptableVolume (DeviceID = "\\?\Volume{4c207a73-a929-4ad6-8e3b-1c90...)
DEBUG: ComputerName: *. MountPoint: C:. LockStatus: 0
DEBUG: EncryptionMethod: 6
DEBUG: Win32EncryptableVolume.IsAutoUnlockEnabled() returned error @{IsAutoUnlockEnabled=False; ReturnValue=2150694937; VolumeKeyProte
ctorID={00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}; PSComputerName=}.ReturnValue
DEBUG: AutoUnlockEnabled: . AutoUnlockKeyProtectorId: 
DEBUG: AutoUnlockKeyStored: False
DEBUG: MetaDataVersion: 2
DEBUG: ConversionStatus: 1. WipingStatus: 0. EncryptionPercentage: 100. WipePercentage: 0
DEBUG: ProtectionStatus: 1.
DEBUG: VolumeType: OperatingSystem. CapacityGB: 476.158199310303
DEBUG: KeyProtectorIds: {*} {*}
DEBUG: KeyProtector[0] = KeyProtectorId: {*}. KeyProtectorType: 1
DEBUG: KeyProtector[1] = KeyProtectorId: {*}. KeyProtectorType: 3
DEBUG: KeyProtectorRecoveryPassword found
DEBUG: End Get-BitLockerVolumeInternal. Return C:
DEBUG: MountPoint: C:
DEBUG: Begin Get-Win32EncryptableVolumeInternal(C:)
DEBUG: Filtering Win32_EncryptableVolumes by C:
DEBUG: End Get-Win32EncryptableVolumeInternal. Return Win32_EncryptableVolume (DeviceID = "\\?\Volume{4c207a73-a929-4ad6-8e3b-1c90...)
BackupToAAD-BitLockerKeyProtector: JSON value not found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x83750009)
At line:1 char:1
+ BackupToAAD-BitLockerKeyProtector -Debug -MountPoint C: -KeyProtector ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException,BackupToAAD-BitLockerKeyProtector
 
DEBUG: ValidMountPoint: 
DEBUG: No valid combination of mountpoint / protector id found
DEBUG: End BackupToAAD-BitLockerKeyProtector. Return

EDIT Bitlocker Policy Screenshots from Intune:
Bitlocker_Policy_1
Bitlocker_Policy_2
Bitlocker_Policy_3

Which build of Windows these devices are running on? Are you running the script as admin? Can you see the recovery key with Get-BitLockerVolume -MountPoint C: | select -ExpandProperty KeyProtector ?

The device I'm testing on is on Windows 11 Enterprise  22H2 Version 10.0.22621 Build 22621. I run the script as local admin. The command you listed returns the recovery key without errors.

Can you run the BackupToAAD-BitLockerKeyProtector command with the -Debug switch and add the output in your question?

I added the Debug log as an Edit to my question.

Could you provide a screenshot of your BitLocker configuration in Intune? Its possible that you're missing one of the required 'silent configuration' requisite settings: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/intune/protect/encrypt-devices#silently-enable-bitlocker-on-devices most notably the TPM / startup key settings.

I added the screenshots of the bitlocker policy in Intune as an edit to my post.

Have you found out any solution?

This issue has not been resolved yet.

I would verify if enterpriseregistration.windows.net is exempted from SSL inspection on your proxy system. In my case, the problem was due to this: every access to the mentioned endpoint was inspected by the cloud proxy
